# How to enable (format) a disk in SunOS then add it to a DiskGroup?

Tags: partition, solaris, storage

```
SERVER # vxdisk list
DEVICE       TYPE            DISK         GROUP        STATUS
c1t0d0s2     auto:none       -            -            online invalid
c1t1d0s2     auto:none       -            -            online invalid
san_vc0_0    auto:sliced     -            -            online
san_vc0_1    auto:sliced     -            -            online
san_vc0_2    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_200p  oraclep_dg1  online
san_vc0_3    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_101p  autosys_dg0  online
san_vc0_4    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_100p  autosys_dg0  online
san_vc0_5    auto            -            -            nolabel
san_vc0_6    auto            -            -            nolabel
san_vc1_0    auto:sliced     -            -            online
san_vc1_1    auto:sliced     -            -            online
san_vc1_2    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_200m  oraclep_dg1  online
san_vc1_3    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_101m  autosys_dg0  online
san_vc1_4    auto:sliced     ldisk_64_100m  autosys_dg0  online
san_vc1_5    auto            -            -            nolabel
san_vc1_6    auto            -            -            nolabel
SERVER #
```

Other information:

```
# vxdisk -s list
...
Disk:   san_vc1_6
type:   auto
flags:  nolabel private autoconfig
error:  Disk is not usable
guid:   -
udid:   AAA%5F2145%5F02006380d018XX00%5F60050768018E03406000000000000475
info:   
...
```

Why? There are new disks, and I can't add them to a DiskGroup because: "Disk is not usable".

```
san_vc1_5
san_vc1_6
san_vc0_5
san_vc0_6
```

How can I enable these new SAN disks + add them to the volume group (vxdiskadm is good for this)
What am I missing? What do I need to do to get the new disks to look like: "auto:sliced"?

Just say if any information is needed... :\

**UPDATE:
when I try to format the disks the format says: "No disks found" :\ - what could the problem be?? Are the disks bad??**

Comment: Did you label the disks?

Comment: I think no. :)))

Comment: how do I do that??

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using Veritas Volume Manager on that box. So from what I can tell there, you need to apply a Sun disklabel to the new disks first and then add them to VxVM.

Format each disk and label it first:

```
# format san_vc0_5
format> label
format> Proceed? yes
```

Then you should be able initialize each disk and add it to Veritas via:

```
# vxdisksetup -i <device> format=sliced
```

Then you can add the disk to the diskgroup you want via:

```
# vxdg -g <diskgroup> adddisk <diskname>=<device>
```

Or vxdiskadm should work.

Note: I don't have any Solaris systems around or VxVM to play with anymore so the syntax for this might be a tad bit off. Here is a link to the VxVM cheatsheet I uploaded a long time ago to Scribd for your reference: http://www.scribd.com/doc/15691130/VxVM-Storage-Foundation-41-Commands

Comment: I tried to format the disk in several ways but the error output is always the same: "No disks found!" - for the format command..hmm.. so it doesn't recognizes the disk? are the disks bad?:O

Comment: could it be that the disks are bad, i mean SunOS doesn't recognizes them well? How can I check that? :\

Comment: Actually try this: 
Tell SunOS to rescan for the disks: `devfsadm -v`.
Then see if format works properly and label the disks, or paste the output of `echo | format` here.
Then tell Veritas to look for new disks via: `vxdctl enable`.

Comment: how do I "label" the disks?:\

Comment: @Lance Does this answer not include the information? Look at the second line in the first code block.

Comment: I just can't format the disks.

Comment: What error are you getting?